# What database is good for holding small images

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have thousands of images in a directory divided in sub folders. I want to take all these images out of the file system and put them in a database. I dont think this kind of data is good for a normal database like sql server. is there a database out there that is good for holding thousands if not millions of small high definition thumbnails? I would like to query this database by id then it provides me the image

Comment: What is wrong with keeping them on the disc?

Comment: You can use Sql Server Express!

Comment: Not to be snarky, but a good database for tons of files is a File System and the ID is the filename. But you could use SQL Server with FILESTREAM columns which essentially stores the files in the file system but access is provided through the file system. Still, the simplest thing that works is possibly to keep the files in the file system and only store the filename in the database if you want to query it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are a few guidelines.**

- If the files are small (say under 4K) and you have a lot (say over 10K), you could see an improvement with storing the files in the database;
- If you want to simplify backup by storing everything in one database, and get replication for free (if you've already got replication set up for your normal database), database would have an advantage;
- If your files are large (say over 100K), storing them in the database will very very likely not be a good idea (SQL databases are not build for that). If you still want to store them in the database, look for something else (like [CouchDB etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net));
- One big disadvantage of storing them in the database is that it's going to be more difficult to access the images. For one, getting the images from disc uses file system caching and optimized paths for streaming files directly from disc over the internet. You lose all this and this may give problems under certain circumstances (again, when your files are large);
- When your files do not change often (which images don't), a database is more often than not, not a good fit. Databases are good in storing and mutating small amounts of data. Large static pieces of information do not fit this model well.

Comment: Sorry to be an ***hole, but you don't "loose" anything in this case, you "lose" it. Please.

Comment: English is not my primary language as you can see in my profile (http://stackoverflow.com/users/446261/pieter). Is this the worst spelling/grammar you've seen from a non native speaker on SO? If you're leaving "constructive" comments like this with all non native speakers, I worry how many of them will stay on SO. Even though: changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem is usually the best way to store big blogs of binary data like images that can be easily identified by an ID, URL or anything unique.